# urllib2 redirect empty page (though code is 200 and geturl() points to new page)

Tags: python, screen-scraping, urllib2

I am trying to access a web page using urllib2 and the automatic redirect in urllib2 does not seem to  retrieve the entire page.
Here is my code:

```
request = urllib2.Request(link)
request.add_header('User-Agent','...')
opener = urllib2.build_opener()

page = opener.open(request)
print(page.code)
print(page.geturl())
print(page.read())
```

a) When link = 'https://www.google.com'. It prints

```
200
https://www.google.com
<!doctype...> Etc. Etc. </script>
```

b) When link = 'https://www.xyz.com/a_link_which_is_redirected.html'. It prints

```
200
https://the_new_link
<blank>
```

However, If I access the 'link' in b) via an internet browser, it correctly displays a page with a form.

Answer (score 0):

View the source of the Google page - it really does end with a script tag. They leave off some of the closing tags because browsers can still interpret it correctly and it saves bandwidth.

[Here are some test redirect pages](http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/Overview.html). Which of those do not work for you?